# a copy of spring-websocket TextMessage,but error

Tags: generics, extends, spring-websocket

I make a copy of TextMessage(org.springframework.web.socket.TextMessage), but the IDE(eclipse release 4.5.2) hint me 3 errors.

[TextMessage in spring framework](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CApik.png)

As you see, the only change is the package.

```
package com.hzh.h5.server.util;

import java.nio.charset.Charset;

import org.springframework.web.socket.AbstractWebSocketMessage;

public final class TextMessage extends AbstractWebSocketMessage<String> {

private static final Charset UTF8_CHARSET = Charset.forName("UTF-8");

private final byte[] bytes;

public TextMessage(CharSequence payload) {
    super(payload.toString(), true);
    this.bytes = null;
}

public TextMessage(byte[] payload) {
    super(new String(payload, UTF8_CHARSET));
    this.bytes = payload;
}

public TextMessage(CharSequence payload, boolean isLast) {
    super(payload.toString(), isLast);
    this.bytes = null;
}


@Override
public int getPayloadLength() {
    return asBytes().length;
}

public byte[] asBytes() {
    return (this.bytes != null ? this.bytes : getPayload().getBytes(UTF8_CHARSET));
}

@Override
protected String toStringPayload() {
    String payload = getPayload();
    return (payload.length() > 10 ? payload.substring(0, 10) + ".." : payload);
}
```

}

the error tip is like this, 'The constructor AbstractWebSocketMessage(T) is not visible'.
[error tip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vu9wA.png)

why i got errors but spring-websocket not?

Answer (score 0):

The class AbstractWebSocketMessage is public,
but the constructors are package scoped.
So therefore "not visible" to your code.

The two classes that extend AbstractWebSocket are TextMessage and BinaryMessage (and they are final)